What is Scarier than That?

Clues:
Left Side:
Set of 5 groups of spheres.
One of Set 1: 5 yellow spheres arranged in a right angle corner
Three of Set 2 : 3 green spheres arranged in a straight line
One of Set 3: 4 blue spheres in a straight line
Group of 3 sets arranged in a corner, consisting of one Set 1, one Set 2, and one set 3.
Numbers on the spheres form a matrix.
[_ _ M E]
[_ _ E K]
[H P E I]
[S C A R]
Stack of red spheres arranged in a pyramid, shown top-down. The dimensions of the base match the dimensions of the grouping to the left.
Middle:
A cat chakra chart.
Right:
Tree spirit (in the likeness of those from the film "Princess Mononoke") wearing a red name tag that says "hello my name is ME".
Instructions: Why am I Afraid of the Lake?
_ _ P _ _
Hint 1:

 The yellow, green, and blue balls stack to form the shape of the red ball pyramid.

Hint 2:

 One set of balls will only stack in one location.

Hint 3:

 One set of balls spells something similar to a word in the title. Might this help align the rest of them?

Hint 4:

 The yellow balls are in the correct orientation to be stacked.


Hm. It's clear what the pyramid should look like. The diagonal spells something familiar and the other diagonal ends in something familiar, too, but I don't know what to make of that.

Try posting a partial answer so others can use your work?

And place my towel on the bounty sunbed? Yeah, why not? ;)

You are scared of the lake because of

 The Kappa

Continuing from M Oehm’s answer:

 Removing the figures name (me) from the Southwest-Northeast diagonal results in SHIRI. Appending “kodama” (which is the figure itself), you have “SHIRIKODAMA”. This leads to a fictitious organ of the human body removed by the kappa, which is a Japanese folklore, living in waters.


While this looks like you're probably right (nice find), any ideas about the significance of the chakras? That's the last remaining unexplained part... Thanks :)

Ah, that must be the answer. Well done! But like Stiv, I wonder where the cat chakras figure.

I have a hazy idea: Znlor, gur fuvevzr sebz gur bgure nafjre yvaxf vg? Gur fuvevzr unf na rlr sbe vgf nahf juvyr gur fuvevxbqnzn va zl nafjre vf gnxra sebz gur nahf. Gur ebbg punxen vf nyfb nffbpvngrq jvgu gur nahf.

Could be. Perhaps it's just that (gur frira punxenf uvag ng gur frira yrggref va gur qvntbanyf).

[Partial answer. Really just the first step. The heavy hints helped.]
The pyramid of balls ...

 ... is a stack of the green, yellow and blue groups of balls. The positions of the groups marked with letters in the base of the pyramid are already set.

 The long blue piece can only form the diagonal from the northeast point of the base to the tip. The three smaller poieces are placed parallel to that piece and the yellow L forms the south and east edges of the second storey.

 I assume that all of the pieces of each kind have the same letters. If so, the pyramid looks like this:



 The ridge from the northeast corner across the tip to the southeast corner reads SCARIER, which also features in the title. The other ridge, read from southwest to northeast, ends in ME, which is the name on the tree spirit's tag.

Some loose thoughts:

 The connection between the pyramid of balls and the cat chakra might be the colours: Each Chakra has several attributes associated with it, for example a number of petals and a colour. The heart chakra is green and has 12 petals – and there are 12 green balls. The navel chakra is yellow and has 10 petals; there are 10 yellow balls. The throat chakra is blue and it has 16 petals, but there are only 8 blue balls in the pyramid. (There's also a red root chakra with four petals.)

 The depicted tree spirits of Japanese folklore are called kodama, so perhaps that name forms something together with the name given on the tag. It might be of note that the trenscription calls attention to the name tag's colour. Then again, that might just be a similarly coloured herring.

 Stiv points out that the word in the sw–ne diagonal, SHIRIME, describes a spirit in Japanese folklore that has an eye between his buttocks. For what it's worth, there is a third-eye chakra. It is indigo and has two petals. (The red root chakra mentioned above might also be relevant.)

 I'm not sure whether there is s single group of two indigo balls, perhaps with the letters M and E on it, and if so, where to place it. Why is the chakra chart of an anthropomorphized cat, not of a human? And where is the lake I'm supposed to be afraid of?

Well, that's as far as I got. Maybe someone else can use this to fill in a connection to cat chakra and tree spirits.

I think you have a typo in the rightmost column of your diagram, the green set of balls should be EKI?

@SquareFinder: Ah, good spot. That's one of the balls that was already there and it should be a K. Fixed that and also added some musings, because I felt like it.

You know the other diagonal actually spells something potentially relevant too...

@Stiv: That's ... scary. (And might lead to indigo and red?)

(Sorry, should have warned you about the content first!!)

No worries, that was all right, if somewhat unexpected. A reply to that screamed for a silly pun, but I thought better of it. (The "scary" was a reference to the puzzle's theme.)

@MOehm you have all the hidden clues detailed in your answer already! The final piece just needs to be put in to place.

Thanks, that's good to know. However, I'm not seeing it, I'm afraid. If anyone else can wrap this up, don't be shy to post your own answer.
